# identify the list of interface a object implements

Tags: java

Is there a way to identify the list of interfaces a object implements. For example: LinkedList implements both List and Queue interfaces.

Is there any Java statement that I can use to determine it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [`Class.getInterfaces()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getInterfaces%28%29):

```
public static void showInterfaces(Object obj) {
    for (Class<?> iface : obj.getClass().getInterfaces()) {
        System.out.println(iface.getName());
    }
}
```

For example, on an implementation of `LinkedList` that prints:

```
java.util.List
java.util.Deque
java.lang.Cloneable
java.io.Serializable
```

Note that `java.util.Queue` isn't displayed by this, because `java.util.Deque` extends it - so if you want *all* the interfaces implemented, you'd need to recurse. For example, with code like this:

```
public static void showInterfaces(Object obj) {
    showInterfaces(obj.getClass());
}

public static void showInterfaces(Class<?> clazz) {
    for (Class<?> iface : clazz.getInterfaces()) {
        System.out.println(iface.getName());
        showInterfaces(iface);
    }
}
```

... the output is:

```
java.util.List
java.util.Collection
java.lang.Iterable
java.util.Deque
java.util.Queue
java.util.Collection
java.lang.Iterable
java.lang.Cloneable
java.io.Serializable
```

... and now you'll note that `Iterable` and `Collection` occur twice :) You could collect the "interfaces seen so far" in a set, to avoid duplication.